# data modeling in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling

i'm new to neo4j trying to model a database the database contain 4 table it is in csv format
table 1(details of employee)
employees( emp_no   ,birth_date ,first_name,    last_name   ,gender,    hire_date)

table 2(detail about who was maneger of which dept)
dept_maneger(emp_no ,dept_no    ,from_date, to_date)

table 3 (detail about department)
departments(dept_no,    dept_name)

table 4(detail about which employe belongs to which dept)
dept_emp(emp_no ,dept_no    ,from_date  ,to_date)

i created the nodes but i want to make a relation ships between department node employee node using from date and to date . how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided no information about your neo4j data model. Here is an example of simple data model that you could use.

You can use nodes labelled `Employee` (for all employees, including managers) and `Department`. For example:

```
(e:Employee {id: 987, birthdate: 222, firstName: 'Fred', lastName: 'Smith', gender: 'male', hired: 12})
(manager:Employee {id: 221, birthdate: 111, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Jones', gender: 'male', hired: 10})
(d:Department {id: 324, name: 'Accounting'})
```

Here are examples of relationships (with the type `WORKS_IN`):

```
(e)-[:WORKS_IN {from: 123, to: 456}]->(d)
(manager)-[:WORKS_IN {from: 234, to: 567, isManager: true}]->(d)
```

The start and end dates for all positions are stored in the `WORKS_IN` relationships. If a person works for the same department as a non-manager and then becomes a manager, s/he would have a new `WORKS_IN` relationship added with the `isManager=true` property (and the date of the promotion as the `from` value).

Comment: i have uploaded the data from csv and created nodes and index

Comment: USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dept_manager.csv" AS row
MATCH (emp_no:Employee {emp_no: row.emp_no})
MATCH (dept_no:departments {dept_no: row.dept_no})
MERGE(Employee)-[:belongs_to{from_date: row.from_date,to_date: row.to_date}]->(departments);

Comment: i tried this quiery for making relation but its not working

Comment: can you tell me whats wrong with it what is the alternative